# $\mathbb Z_p[T]/(T^a,p^b)\cong\mathbb Z_p[[T]]/(T^a,p^b)$

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $a,b\in \mathbb N,$ then

$$\mathbb  Z_p[T]/(T^a,p^b)\cong\mathbb Z_p[[T]]/(T^a,p^b)$$

> 1.What is this isomorphism ?
>
> 2.How to prove that $|\mathbb Z_p[[T]]/(T,p)^t|=p^{t(t+1)/2}$

Now  Let $X$ be a $\mathbb Z_p[[T]]-$module.

> 3.we can view $X$ as a $\mathbb Z_p-$module ?

Comment: Is $\Bbb Z_p$ the $p$-adics or the field with $p$ elements?

Comment: @PVAL yes the ring of $p-$adic integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for 1: What is the most natural homomorphism, from $\Bbb Z_p[T] \rightarrow \Bbb Z_p[[T]]$? Your isomorphism is induced from that homomorphism.

Hint for 2: A similar argument to 1. shows $\mathbb Z_p[[T]]/(T,p)^t \cong \mathbb  Z_p[T]/(T,p)^t$. Note $\mathbb Z_p/(p^t) \cong  \mathbb Z/p^t\mathbb Z$, and now you can just work out what $\mathbb Z_p[T]/(T,p)^t$ is.

Hint for 3:For any commutative rings $R$ and $S$, a homomorphism of rings $\phi : R\rightarrow S$ makes every $S$-module a $R$-module in a natural way.

Comment: obviously the natural injection :)

Comment: thank you for 1 can you explain more

Comment: I think $\mathbb Z_p[[T]]/(T,p)^t\cong \mathbb Z_p[T]/(T,p)^t$ is not just!!

Comment: The induced map from the natural injection is clearly injective. It is surjective since we can write every element of the quotient ring of the power series with a polynomial representative, since $T^t \in (T,p)^t$.